# How to create a group by with 2 counts using 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

It would be great if I could get some advice here. I am trying to create a GROUP BY with 2 different counts using information from 2 tables. I managed to create a GROUP BY that has just one of the two counts that I want, but got stuck there. Help is appreciated!

```
Table_1 
ID | Date     | Error_code 
101| 01/11/19 | A 
102| 01/11/19 | B 
103| 02/11/19 | A 
104| 03/11/19 | A 

Table_2 
ID | Status_code 
101| 1 
102| 2 
103| 1 
104| 1
```

Eventually I'm trying to achieve this particular result:

```
date     | error_code | count_status_code_1 | count_status_code_2 
01/11/19 | A          | 1                   | 1 
02/11/19 | A          | 0                   | 0 
03/11/19 | A          | 1                   | 0
```

Here is what I got so far:

```sql
SELECT date, 
       error_code, 
       Count(*) AS count_status_code_1 
FROM   table_1 
       JOIN table_2 
         ON table_1.id = table_2.id 
WHERE  error_code = 'A' 
       AND status_code = 1 
GROUP  BY date, 
          error_code 
ORDER  BY date ASC;
```

How should I rework the code in order to add the second count column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL or PostGreSQL ? They're different products.

Comment: Btw, are you sure about the results ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! My bad but I'm using postgresql in particular to make this query. However I also am trying to learn MySQL, so I thought it'll be nice to see how different it would be in that particular system as well

Comment: @Jeremy, based on your data, your where clause will never count count_status_code_2. Based on your desired result, my answer below should get you that. I think, if at all possible reconsider your desired result set. For example, string_agg on your error code would produce A,B and your desired result set would make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Conditional Aggregation :

```
select date, error_code, 
       sum(case when Status_code =1 then 1 else 0 end) as count_status_code_1,
       sum(case when Status_code =2 then 1 else 0 end) as count_status_code_2
  from table_1 t1
  join table_2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
 where error_code = 'A' 
 group by date, error_code
 order by date;
```

Comment: You probably want `sum` instead of `count`.

Comment: + you should be able to do SUM(status_code =1) and SUM (status_code=2)

Comment: This query will filter out status_code 2, where error_code = 'A' because status_code 2 is error_code B

Comment: some rules differ depending of DBMS dialects. You cannot apply yours for PostGreSQL @Gosfly

Comment: That's right, this will work if this is MySQL. At the moment, we still don't know which DBMS he is using.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: however you can simplify the expression as `sum(case when Status_code =1 then 1 end) as count_status_code_1`, since `sum()` ignore `null`s. Anyway your answer is correct I upvoted it already.

Comment: thank you @GMB but unfortunately sum doesn't ignore nulls. Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4b8698b3b099b8b2a7290b2684badeb2)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired results and not the SQL that was started. The desired result set has to not display 'B' error code but still tally the results of it's linked status codes. In order to do that, a decision needs to be made as to how we only display Error Code 'A' but still count the status codes that are tied to error code 'B'. In order to only display 'A' I decided to get the first value of error codes, group them by Date and then order them by Error code. I could have also ordered them by status ID. Lastly, sum the two status code columns. Do not filter out 'B' or status code because you will not get the count.

```
SELECT
     DATE
    ,Ecode Error_code
    ,SUM(count_status_code_1) count_status_code_1
    ,SUM(count_status_code_2) count_status_code_2
FROM
(
    SELECT
       Date
      ,FIRST_VALUE(Error_code)  OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Error_code) ECode
      ,CASE WHEN Status_code = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END count_status_code_1
      ,CASE WHEN Status_code = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END count_status_code_2
     FROM
       Table1
     JOIN
       Table2 ON Table2.ID = Table1.ID
 ) Error_Table
 GROUP BY
    Date, Error_code
 ORDER BY Date
```

I urge you to reconsider your desired result so that the error_code columnn displays both errors 'A,B'. Here's how to do that in

**PostgreSQL**

```
SELECT
       Date
      ,string_agg(Error_code, ',') Error_code
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status_code = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_status_code_1
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status_code = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_status_code_2
     FROM
       Table1
     JOIN
       Table2 ON Table2.ID = Table1.ID
 GROUP BY
    Date
 ORDER BY Date
```

Here's how in

**MySQL**

```
 SELECT
       Date
      ,group_concat(Error_code) Error_code
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status_code = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_status_code_1
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status_code = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_status_code_2
     FROM
       Table1
     JOIN
       Table2 ON Table2.ID = Table1.ID
 GROUP BY
    Date
 ORDER BY Date
```